# What's the difference between a Rack app and a Sinatra app?

Tags: sinatra, rack

What advantages do I have with a Rack app over a sinatra app?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the asker wants the merits of keeping it to just Rack.

Considering Sinatra is already an extremely thin & minimalistic veneer for typical web applications, my short answer will be: when your needs are atypical and/or spartan

when you don't even need...

- layout/ templating - you enjoy writing out raw string http content
- cookies and sessions - no memory, everything is one-shot default
- methods - your app abuses the URL and HTTP VERB in crazy ass ways
- to be modern - you have nostalgia with CGI/perl scripts in the 90s
- any structure - your app returns time of day in text. per se.

I use Sinatra because I believe this is the lowest footprint you can really focus on business function of my apps, without dealing with web server nitty-gritties (Rails conversely is monoli-thick!) and still have an intuitive MVC-like project structure

You gain really little except code lines, and a smarmy twinkle in your eye when impressing geeks
honest.

p.s.: I maintain a nice skeleton for my own needs at http://github.com/codepants/yasumi

Answer (score 3):

> Rack, a modular Ruby webserver interface Rack provides a minimal,
>   modular and adaptable interface for developing web applications in
>   Ruby. By wrapping HTTP requests and responses in the simplest way
>   possible, it unifies and distills the API for web servers, web
>   frameworks, and software in between (the so-called middleware) into a
>   single method call.

Rack is a bare-bones middleware and therefore a bit more lightweight but doesn't help you that much when building complex applications.

> Sinatra is a Domain Specific Language (DSL) for quickly creating web-applications in Ruby.
>
> It keeps a minimal feature set, leaving the developer to use the tools
>   that best suit them and their application.

Sinatra is a small "framework" on top of Rack providing you with nifty methods to get up running quickly. It's not that lightweight as Rack but still as light as a cloud in the sky.